# PHP Session not working in PHP5

Tags: php, session

I have 2 pages: login.php and index.php. Both pages start with

```
session_start();
```

When I set

```
$_SESSION['user'] = "name";
```

in login.php and than open index.php, my session object is empty. How come?

EDIT:

I found the problem: IE 7. I had to grand access to my domain. However, I thought a session is stored on the server, instead of the client? Than why do I have IE grand access to my domain? (http://www.pcwindowstips.com/2007/09/04/how-to-enable-cookies-in-internet-explorer-7/)

Comment: that's too little information. do you have cookies enabled?

Comment: do you have error reporting activated ? are there any error / warnings showned ?

Comment: Good point. I check in FireFox and there it does work. However in IE 7 it doesn't work. Maybe something to do with cookies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought a session is stored on the server, instead of the client? Than why do I have IE grant access to my domain? (http://www.pcwindowstips.com/2007/09/04/how-to-enable-cookies-in-internet-explorer-7/)

The way sessions work is that a session cookie is stored for the site, which contains your session ID.  The only way the server knows who you are is when it reads the session ID cookie on every page load.  All of the $_SESSION data is stored on the server for each user, but the cookie must be set for the server to know which $_SESSION data to retrieve.

This is also why you can essentially "become" another user if you obtain their session id cookie.

Comment: aah thnx, that make things clear! But is there a workaround for IE7 for this problem?

Comment: just enable cookies.  most sites on the web today will be broken with cookies disabled anyway, i don't think it's a case you have to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorers have a stricter cookie policy than most other browsers. Check your [session cookie parameters](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) (see also [`session_get_cookie_params()`](http://docs.php.net/session_get_cookie_params)) and try to replace the default values by explicit values where possible. Additionally you might send a [fake P3P policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537343(VS.85).aspx) to satisfy the Internet Explorers.

Comment: Thnx, when i do print_r(session_get_cookie_params) I see this: Array ( [lifetime] => 0 [path] => / [domain] => [secure] => [httponly] => ) How can I make this work?

Comment: And how do I send a fake p3p policy? I can't found it on Google

Comment: Set `session.cookie_domain` to the domain you want to use the cookies in. And the compact P3P policy can be sent with the `header` function.

Comment: `session.cookie_domain` must be set in the php.ini? If so, i don't have access to that..

Comment: No, you can set it either with the `ini_set` or `session_set_cookie_params` function. See “changable” column in http://docs.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this variable in php.ini is mapping to an existing path

session.save_path = "c:/wrong/path"

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that happened to me that might shed light for someone. My session wasn't working properly. IE 8 and Firefox were losing the session information.

I included a file. That included file had an extra carriage return after the trailing &ques?>

That carriage return started the session. I put session_start after the include. BOOM.

Answer (score 1):

Not much info here, I'll try to use my psychic powers.

After the user logs in, do you set the session var and then redirect the user to index.php using an http header?  If so, I don't think the session cookie gets sent to the user.  If that is the case, the solutions are:

1. call session_start() when the login form is initially displayed (not just after the user posts back to it); or:
2. display a "login successful!" message and then redirect with a meta-refresh, or just provide a link to index.php.

---

You can also try to dump the session ID on both pages, to see if you are somehow starting a new session:

```
echo 'Session ID is: ' . SID . "<br/>\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need verify if the cookies are enabled and nothing ( this includes blank lines in the beginning or in the end  of archive) sent to browser before you call session_start().